# How to unlock the ethereum contract account?

Tags: accounts, ethereum-wallet-dapp, multisignature

I installed the package [from this link](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/tree/master) and its working fine. Then I create the one multisig contract. when creating the contract I got one new address.

I can deposit that address but for withdraw process it shows the error message like you need to unlock the account on send transaction process on Web3 API.

I am also trying the unlock function but here we need to provide the password but for this contract address we didn't know the password.

So please help anyone to unlock the contract account. I should use that address for withdraw process because by that process only the multisig process working.

Comment: What is the code of the contract? Do you unlock the account prior to making any transactions from it? You can have a look at thi [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-can-i-create-a-multisignature-address-on-ethereum) thread with a number of multisig wallet dapps.

Comment: I saw the above link but here also just elaborate about the contract creation but i created the contract and got the contract address. In my website i need to done the withdraw process by this address for that purpose i need to unlock this account. how it is possible.

Comment: Can you post the contract's code?

Comment: already i give the this link https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/tree/master  i install this package and create the contract using this. when create the contract i got one address. from that address i need to transfer the amount

Comment: The contracts never have a private key/password. They do not need to be locked/unlocked, contract addresses are owned by EOAs. You need to unlock the account from which the contract was deployed.

Answer (score 1):

A multisignature wallet is a contract located at an [externally owned account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5828/87).

You neither have access to its related private key nor any kind of password to access it.

To 'unlock' it, the wallet dapp asks you to unlock the onwing account of the multisignature contract. So you have to unlock one of your local accounts which is one of the accounts with access to the contract wallet, not the contract account itself.