# Multisig function calls

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, signature, multisignature

I am making a dapp in which ethereum user accounts that call certain functions are rewarded with an ERC20 token. All the dapp is based on functions using only one ethereum account as parameter. But if several people want to collaborate and call a function together then the smart contract needs to be able to treat that case. Instead of changing all functions I thought about the possibility offered by multisig. 
For instance if 3 users create a multisig address on ethereum and call the action with a multisig wallet as the multisig account. Is it possible and do you see anything wrong with this approach? Is metamask able to do it if not is it technically possible to develop a wallet able to handle the multisig transactions signatures process ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get the answer from [How can I create a multisignature address on Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6/how-can-i-create-a-multisignature-address-on-ethereum)

Another option is to add some functionality in your contract to create new multisig contract with predefined functionality and storage for your case (like array of participants addresses which you can access from your contract)

Comment: Ok thank you, I will probably have to add some functionality then. If I let this responsability to the wallet it can be more complicated to guaranty the multisig is done properly

Comment: I would recommend to use Gnosis Multisig Wallet solution

https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet

https://medium.com/coinmonks/guide-to-using-the-gnosis-multisig-wallet-erc20-token-2122f8024265